# Como criar um atalho dentro de página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, teclado

Para adicionar um novo item no meu banco de dados existe o botão <kbd>Adicionar</kbd>, no entanto gostaria de adicionar um atalho para que exerça a mesma função do botão. Por exemplo quando é clicado o <kbd>E</kbd> em qualquer pergunta no SO, essa mesma entra em modo de edição.

No meu caso pensei algo como <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> para inserir um novo item.

Usando o `keydown` é possível detectar que foi pressionado apenas uma tecla, como mostra o exemplo abaixo:

```js
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 16) {   
      alert("O código "+ e.which + " que representa o Shift foi precionado");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Para criar o atalho eu pensei algo do tipo:

```
if (e.keyCode == 16 && e.keyCode == 78)
```

Que neste caso o `78` corresponde o <kbd>n</kbd>, porém não funcionou desta forma.

Como eu poderia criar uma atalho na minha pagina web que reconheceria o comando <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O objeto `evento` traz as propriedades somente leitura [shiftKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey), [ctrlKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/shiftKey), [altKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/altKey), [metaKey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/metaKey) (tecla commando do Mac ou tecla Windows), que podem ser **true** ou **false**.

Você pode construir algo assim:

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 78 && e.shiftKey) {   
      alert("shift+n");
    }
});
```

A função repassada ao keydown é invocada cada vez que uma tecla é **pressionada**: se eu pressionar o <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, ele vai disparar o evento, e, mesmo com ele pressionado, se eu teclar o <kbd>N</kbd>, ele vai disparar novamente o evento (segunda vez). Mas aí existe aquela propriedade que informa que o <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> está pressionado.

Então se você checar com o `if (e.keyCode == 16 && e.keyCode == 78)`, não irá resultar em `true` por que o evento é disparado duas vezes:

1. quando o <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> é pressionado, evento disparado pela primeira vez com o `keyCode` `16` e `shiftKey`: `true` (por que é o shift que foi pressionado);
2. quando o <kbd>N</kbd> é pressionado, evento disparado pela segunda vez com o `keyCode` `78` e `shiftKey`: `true`.

Por fim, a documentação diz que, se eu ficar pressionando uma tecla, ele irá invocar a função toda vez que o sistema operacional repeti-la. Por exemplo, se você pressionar e ficar segurando a tecla <kbd>A</kbd>, ele irá invocar o `.keyDown` uma vez, esperar um pouco, e logo em seguida irá invocá-la várias vezes na sequência, como se o usuário tivesse repetidamente apertando a tecla, pois o sistema operacional a repete (como em qualquer editor se ficarmos segurando uma tecla por um tempo: ela será repetida várias vezes).

Mas o mesmo comportamento não acontece com algumas teclas especiais, dentre elas o <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>. O sistema operacional não a repete quando você a mantém pressionada.

Criei um fiddle que monitora o keydown e adiciona uma linha na tabela a cada tecla pressionada, para testes: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/texabz01/

Comment: Funcionou assim cara, você sabe me dizer por qual motivo não funcionou assim: `if (e.keyCode == 16 && e.keyCode == 78)` considerando que o keyCode 16 refere-se ao shift  ?

Comment: @AckLay editei minha resposta com uma complementação e criei um fiddle para testar esses cenários. Abraços

Comment: Ótimo exemplo +1

Answer (score 3):

O objeto `event` traz informações como:

- event.ctrlKey
- event.altKey
- event.metaKey
- event.shiftKey

Tente:

```js
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {

        if( event.which === 78 && event.shiftKey ) {
            alert('pressione SHIFT+N');
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Funcionou também assim cara, você sabe me dizer por qual motivo não funcionou assim: `if (e.keyCode == 16 && e.keyCode == 78)` considerando que o keyCode 16 refere-se ao shift  ?

Comment: Acredito que basicamente `keydown` armazene apenas uma `keyCode` por vez, e só pode ser chamada novamente se a tecla pressionado anteriormente não estiver mais pressionada